# Android KitKat : All my app content appears behind the ActionBar and StatusBar after changing StatusBar color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles, android-4.4-kitkat

I've created a separate xml style file targeting KitKat and I've managed to change the color of the status bar. The only side-effect as seen on the picture, all the content is now moved up beneath the status bar. My question is how can I change the color of the status bar without overlaying this or how can I know the exact top margin I need to put on my content so its starts after the ActionBar and not beneath. Of course I need this to behave as expected on all screen sizes and densities. Thank you

[image: Navigation drawer and all content appears beneath the ActionBar and Status Bar]

values-v19/styles.xml

```
<style name="ThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>

        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should add the following to the top of the view(s)

```
android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

If you're using the Support Library for the action bar, you need to remove the android: prefix

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

By enabling translucent system bars, your layout will fill the area behind the system bars, so you must also enable *fitsSystemWindows* for the portion of your layout that should not be covered by the system bars.

Comment: Is it like this android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize" ? Can you provide the same line for the support library. Does it also take into account the status bar ? I am eager to try but it won't work, I tried removing the 'android:' prefix from the string value

Comment: ok thank you it works, just one thing, it doesnt account for the status bar height so i need to figure that one

Comment: you must also enable fitsSystemWindows for the portion of your layout that should not be covered by the system bars

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

You can add

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

in your XML File

Comment: This doesn't work if you have translucent action bar (this is important aspect of the question). The source you've mentioned states that you have to apply top margin/padding (section Specify Layout Top-margin)

Comment: Sorry, you're right, updated the answer with another solution i have found

Answer (score 1):

Remove from your layout

```
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```